# How to subtract 30 days from current date

Tags: java, android

I just need to know how to **subtract a number of days** from current date.
dateFrom want to be dateTo - 30 days.

```
Date dateFrom;
Date dateTo;

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
dateTo = new Date();
txtDateTo.setText(dateFormat.format(dateTo));
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: show your code first.

Comment: please update the question with some code snippet or describe in such way that which class you have used so far to get a date so the contributors will able to help you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
c.setTime(sdf.parse(date));
c.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);
Date newDate = c.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

> Adds or subtracts the specified amount of time to the given calendar
>   field, based on the calendar's rules. For example, to subtract 30 days
>   from the current time of the calendar, you can achieve it by calling:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); // this would default to now
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Subtract day of month

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
 c.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -30);
```